# Java, Generics, Merge, Comparable

Tags: java, generics, merge, comparable

Here is my question:

A method named merge that concatenates 2 unordered lists into a third. Assume that list_1 and list_2 don't have any keys in common. The resulting list should be an unsorted list that contains all of the items from list_1 and list_2 (preserve the order).

The problem that I am having is that I need to answer this question using generics. I have the code for the normal merge method which is the following..

```
// Merge Method
    public OrderedArrayList merge(OrderedArrayList list2){
        OrderedArrayList result = new OrderedArrayList(length + list2.length);
        int list1Index = 0;
        int list2Index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.maxSize; i++) {
            if (list1Index == list.length) {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            } else if (list2Index == list2.length) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else if (list[list1Index] < list2.list[list2Index]) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have been working on the generics section for days. SOS!!
Here are my classes:

```
//Interface: ArrayListADT 
//works for int 
public interface ArrayListADT1<T> extends Comparable{ 
    public boolean isEmpty(); //Method to determine whether the list is empty. 
    public boolean isFull();  //Method to determine whether the list is full. 
    public int listSize();    //Method to return the number of elements in the list. 
    public int maxListSize(); //Method to return the maximum size of the list. 
    public void print();      //Method to output the elements of the list. 
    public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, T item); //Method to determine whether item is the same as the item in the list at location. 
    public void insertAt(int location, T insertItem);   //Method to insert insertItem in the list at the position 
    public void insertEnd(T insertItem); //Method to insert insertItem at the end of the list. 
    public void removeAt(int location);  //Method to remove the item from the list at location. 
    public T retrieveAt(int location);   //Method to retrieve the element from the list at location. 
    public void replaceAt(int location, T repItem); //Method to replace the element in the list at location with repItem. 
    public void clearList();  //Method to remove all the elements from the list. 
    public int search(T searchItem);    //Method to determine whether searchItem is in the list. 
    public void remove(T removeItem);   //Method to remove an item from the list. 
}

//Class: ArrayListClass1<T> implements 
//Interface: ArrayListADT 
public abstract class ArrayListClass1<T> implements ArrayListADT1<T>, Comparable{
    protected int length; // to store the length of the list
    protected int maxSize; // to store the maximum size of the list
    protected T[] list; // array to hold the list elements

    // Default constructor
    public ArrayListClass1() {
        maxSize = 100;
        length = 0;
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
    }

    // Alternate Constructor
    public ArrayListClass1(int size) {
        if (size <= 0) {
            System.err.println("The array size must be positive. Creating an array of size 100.");
            maxSize = 100;
        } else
            maxSize = size;
        length = 0;
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (length == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return (length == maxSize);
    }

    public int listSize() {
        return length;
    }

    public int maxListSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, T item) {
        if (location < 0 || location >= length) {
            System.err.println("The location of the item to be compared is out of range.");
            return false;
        }
        return list[location] == item;
    }

    public void clearList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            list[i] = null;
        length = 0;
        System.gc(); // invoke the Java garbage collector
    }

    public void removeAt(int location) {
        if (location < 0 || location >= length)
            System.err.println("The location of the item to be removed is out of range.");
        else {
            for (int i = location; i < length - 1; i++)
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
            length--;
        }
    }

    public T retrieveAt(int location) {
        if (location < 0 || location >= length) {
            System.err.println("The location of the item to be retrieved is out of range.");
            return null;
        } else
            return list[location];
    }

    public abstract void insertAt(int location, T insertItem);

    public abstract void insertEnd(T insertItem);

    public abstract void replaceAt(int location, T repItem);

    public abstract int search(T searchItem);

    public abstract void remove(T removeItem);
}

//Class: OrderedArrayList1 extends 
//Super class: ArrayListClass 
public class OrderedArrayList1<T> extends ArrayListClass1<T>{

  public OrderedArrayList1() {
    super();
  }

  public OrderedArrayList1(int size) {
    super(size);
  }

  // implementation for abstract methods defined in ArrayListClass

  // ordered list --> binary search
  public int search(T item) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = length - 1;
    int middle = -1;

    while (first <= last) {
      middle = (first + last) / 2;
      Comparable<T> listElem = (Comparable<T>) list[middle];
      if (listElem.compareTo(item)==0)
        return middle;
      else
        if (listElem.compareTo(item) > 0)
        last = middle - 1;
      else
        first = middle + 1;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public void insert(T item) {
    int loc;
    boolean found = false;
    if (length == 0) // list is empty
      list[length++] = item; // insert item and increment length
    else if (length == maxSize) // list is full
      System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    else {
      for (loc = 0; loc < length; loc++) {
        Comparable<T> temp = (Comparable<T>) list[loc];
        if (temp.compareTo(item) >= 0) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      // starting at the end, shift right
      for (int i = length; i > loc; i--)
        list[i] = list[i - 1];
      list[loc] = item; // insert in place
      length++;
    }
  }

  /*
   * Another version for insert:
   * public void insert(int item) {
   * int loc;
   * boolean found = false;
   * if (length == 0) //list is empty
   * list[length++] = item; //insert item and increment length
   * else if (length == maxSize) //list is full
   * System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
   * else {
   * int i = length - 1;
   * while (i >= 0 && list[i] > item) {
   * list[i + 1] = list[i];
   * i--;
   * }
   * list[i + 1] = item; // Insert item
   * length++;
   * }
   * }
   */

  public void insertAt(int location, T item) {
    if (location < 0 || location >= maxSize)
      System.err.println("The position of the item to be inserted is out of range.");
    else if (length == maxSize) // the list is full
      System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    else {
      System.out.println("Cannot do it, this is a sorted list. Doing insert in place (call to insert).");
      insert(item);
    }
  }

  public void insertEnd(T item) {
    if (length == maxSize) // the list is full
      System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list.");
    else {
      System.out.println("Cannot do it, this is a sorted list. Doing insert in place (call to insert).");
      insert(item);
    }
  }

  public void replaceAt(int location, T item) {
    // the list is sorted!
    // is actually removing the element at location and inserting item in place
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
      System.err.println("The position of the item to be replaced is out of range.");
    else {
      removeAt(location);// method in ArrayListClass
      insert(item);
    }
  }

  public void remove(T item) {
    int loc;
    if (length == 0)
      System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty list.");
    else {
      loc = search(item);
      if (loc != -1)
        removeAt(loc);// method in ArrayListClass
      else
        System.out.println("The item to be deleted is not in the list.");
    }
  }

  /*
   * Another version for remove:
   * public void remove(T item) {
   * int loc;
   * if (length == 0)
   * System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty list.");
   * else {
   * loc = search(item);
   * if (loc != -1) {
   * for(int i = loc; i < length - 1; i++)
   * list[i] = list[i + 1]; //shift left
   * length--;
   * }
   * else
   * System.out.println("The item to be deleted is not in the list.");
   * }
   * }
   */

  /*
   * 
   * KATHERINE'S
   * 
   */
  // The start of Assignment 3
  // Merge Method

  public OrderedArrayList1<T> merge(OrderedArrayList1<T> list2){
    OrderedArrayList1 result = new OrderedArrayList1(length + list2.length);
    int list1Index = 0;
    int list2Index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.maxSize; i++) {
      Comparable<T> temp = (Comparable<T>)list[list1Index];
      T [] temp1 = new T list2[list1Index];
      if (list1Index.equals(list[list1Index])) {
        result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
        list2Index++;
      } else if (list2Index.equals(list[list1Index])) {
        result.insert(list[list1Index]);
        list1Index++;

      }else if (temp.compareTo(list2) < 0) {
        result.insert(list[list1Index]);
        list1Index++;
      } else {
        result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
        list2Index++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  // Split Method
  public <T extends Comparable<T> > void split(OrderedArrayList1<T> lessThanKey, OrderedArrayList1<T> greaterThanKey, T splitKey) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      T temp = (T)list[i];
      if (temp.compareTo(splitKey)<0)
        lessThanKey.insert(temp);
      else
        greaterThanKey.insert(temp);
    }
  }
}
```

I have been working on the Merge Generics method for around 12 hours now. I have tried sooo many different ways. I would REALLY appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: What is the question? You need to ask a specific question. You can't also just dump code, the code you provide must be the bare minimum required to exhibit your problem completely. Please refer to this guide and the links within on how to ask a good question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Roman I don't think the duplicate is fair...give her a chance to edit the question. Her other question was asking about a specific compiler error which has been resolved. It's fine to ask multiple questions about the same code as long as the questions are different.

Comment: @Radiodef Maybe I am not seeing something, but what is different in the other question? Both are about converting that same code from non-generic to generics, except the other question shows an attempt at solving the problem and a specific error that arose, while this one mentions none of that. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Roman Well I guess what I mean is that we need to give more constructive help sometimes than just flagging or what have you. For example I don't think she's implemented Andy's suggestion correctly so maybe she needs to post a comment on his answer and ask for some sort of clarification. But maybe she has some other problem so give her a chance to respond before taking moderation action. (I see quite a few possible other problems but I don't know where to begin ;p. )

Comment: In theory all you should have to do to make `merge` generic is change the `OrderedArrayList`s to `OrderedArrayList<T>`s. If you need e.g. some syntax or a compiler error explained we're happy to help, but we just need a more specific problem to address. Specific questions get specific answers. Using the @ sign when you respond in a comment (like Roman and I did ) sends the user a notification.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for sticking up for me :D But I did try to fix my problem with the advice from my first question. But I was still having multiple issues. This question was for an assignment in my class. The due date was today, and I just turned it in. I will post her solution later in the week. I tried everyone's suggestions multiple times. But I think Radiodef is right, that I have multiple issues going on at once. Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Let's tackle this step by step.

First, you need to merge two lists together. This is only possible if the lists contain elements of the same type and, logically, the result will be a new list of the same type. So, we end up with the following method:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> merge(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
    final List<T> merged = new ArrayList<T>();
    merged.addAll(first);
    merged.addAll(second);
    return merged;
}
```

You just need to use your custom list implementation, but the principle is the same.

Second, when implementing your list, don't extend Comparable. You should only need that if you need to compare the instances of your class. Instead, make the elements comparable like in the example method.